# Can I make vim cursorcolumn be set only when on columns other than 1?

Tags: vim

I don't like seeing the highlight for column 1, which is obvious and is too close to the numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put something like this in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd  CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * call CS()

function CS()
    if col(".") > 1
        set cursorcolumn
    else
        set nocursorcolumn
    endif
endfunction
```

For more information, read

```
:h autocmd
:h CursorMoved
:h col()
:h cursorcolumn
```

---

Edit: In the help to CursorMoved there is written

> Careful: This is triggered very often, don't
>   do anything that the user does not expect or
>   that is slow.

So I hope this is a little bit better (=quicker) version

```
function CS()
    if &cuc == 0 && col(".") != 1
        set cuc
    elseif &cuc == 1 && col(".") == 1
        set nocuc
    endif
endfunction
```

Before the function sets anything, it checks if cursorcolumn (`&cuc`) is set or not (try `:echo &cuc` to see the value). So it sets only in occurrence of desired change of cursor position, not every time cursor moves.

`:h expr-option`